# MVC Partial Views and Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a partial view which is essentially a widget. I want to have between 1 and 'n' of these on the same page.

My issue I'm having is I can't get javascript to execute in each one.

e.g.

Index.cshtml

```
<div>
   @Html.Partial("_ButtonPartialView")
    <br/>
    <br />
   @Html.Partial("_ButtonPartialView")
</div>
```

_ButtonPartialView.cshtml

```
<h2>ButtonView</h2>
<button id="foo">
    on
</button>
```

BundleConfig.cs

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/test").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/test.js"));
```

Layout.cshtml

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/test")
```

test.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#foo').click (function() {
        if ($('#foo').html() === 'on') {
            $('#foo').html('off');
        } else {
            $('#foo').html("on");
        }
    });
});
```

My problem is, when i click the first button it switches between on and off fine. When I click the second button, nothing happens!

My bigger issue, if I can get this to work is. I obviously want all my Partial Views to be independent. e.g. I don't want to click one button and they all trigger. They are all going to be passed a model and I need to write JS that will do stuff with that model and display the information.

So each widget needs to be independent.

Thanks

Comment: first thing id is unique, use class instead for button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the `id` must be unique. If you want to reference the button by id you'll need to generate unique ids.

A cleaner way is to use a class selector instead with `$(this)` to reference the button instance that triggered the event.

```
$(".foo").on("click", function(e) {
    var btn = $(this);
    var state = btn.html();
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

to trigger script on dynamically added content you need to tie the event to the document.  change your click event to

```
$(document).on('click', '#foo', function() {
    if ($('#foo').html() === 'on') {
        $('#foo').html('off');
    } else {
        $('#foo').html("on");
    }
});
```

then as mentioned in the other answer change the selector to be partial specific